# Theme stylesheet not called properly on cloned website

Tags: css, clone-site

After cloning a WP website locally everything works fine except main theme stylesheet is called is the following way:

```
http://127.0.0.1/my_site/wp-content/themes/mycollege/?ver=3
```

instead of the original version online:

```
http://www.my_site.com/wp-content/themes/mycollege/style.css?ver=3
```

Of course the first one doesn't work.

As I didn't touch anything either in template files or admin settings, where does this problem come from and how to solve it?

Comment: How are you including the stylesheet?

Answer (score 0):

If you used a plugin to move the site.  I use WP Migration for instance. When you install the migrated version to your local environment, the plugin will change the domain to whatever your local domain is.  In your case it is 127.0.0.1.  The reason it does this is that many of the options are stored in a serialized array.  If the original domain name has a different number of characters than the new sites domain the serialized arrays will be unreadable and all the settings will be lost.

I think that is what you were asking. Or was it that the style.css?ver=3 part was missing the style.css?

Comment: "Or was it that the style.css?ver=3 part was missing the style.css?" : yes, that.